# Akka.net | MongoDB only loads one event

Tags: mongodb, persistence, akka.net

I'm currently working with akka on a new project. But now I'm stuck with a problem.

I added a mongo db to my project and set the journal and snapshotstore. I can persist events and the events will be stored in the database. That works great.

[image]

But when I restart the application and the actor starts to recovering the events, the actor only restore the first event. It seems that the Recovery upper SequenceNr Limit is set to 1 but I've already checked that.
After the recovery of this first event the actor received the message RecoveryCompleted and the recovery process is finished.

The recovery methods

```
private void recovers()
{
    Recover<TenantCreated>(evt =>
    {
        applyEvent(evt);
        Context.System.EventStream.Publish(evt);
    
    });

    Recover<TenantDeleted>(evt =>
    {
        applyEvent(evt);
        Context.System.EventStream.Publish(evt);
    });

    Recover<SnapshotOffer>(snapshot =>
    {
        this.state = (TenantCollection)snapshot.Snapshot;
    });

    Recover<RecoveryCompleted>(msg =>
    {
    });
}
```

One method that persists an event

```
Command<CreateTenant>(command =>
{
    Persist(new TenantCreated(command.Id, command.UserId, command.Name, new Guid(command.Id).ToString("N")), evt =>
    {
        var newTenant = applyEvent(evt);

        newTenant.Tell(command);

        persistAndPublishEvent(evt);
    });
});
```

My akka configuration.
The connectionString will be loaded with a fallback. With this I can set the connectionString as an environment variable.

```
persistence {
    journal {
        plugin = "akka.persistence.journal.mongodb"
        mongodb {
            class = "Akka.Persistence.MongoDb.Journal.MongoDbJournal, Akka.Persistence.MongoDb"
            collection = "EventJournal"
            plugin-dispatcher = "akka.actor.default-dispatcher"
        }
    }

    snapshot-store {
        plugin = "akka.persistence.snapshot-store.mongodb"
        mongodb {
            class = "Akka.Persistence.MongoDb.Snapshot.MongoDbSnapshotStore, Akka.Persistence.MongoDb"
            collection = "SnapshotStore"
            plugin-dispatcher = "akka.actor.default-dispatcher"
        }
    }
}
```

What is the problem?

Does anyone has the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, looks like this is a bug after all - deleting the metadata table exposed it.

It's because we don't apply indexes to the collections by default (and haven't ever, by the looks of it - which we missed because the configurations in our test suites are different:) https://github.com/akkadotnet/Akka.Persistence.MongoDB/blob/552a29eed4c839fe4f91fceeb70bb29eb17d1315/src/Akka.Persistence.MongoDb/reference.conf#L11

So this was really helpful - turns out our large users never had this issue because they ran with `auto-initialize=on` in their configurations this entire time. You were affected by the defaults being different.

https://github.com/akkadotnet/Akka.Persistence.MongoDB/releases/tag/1.4.21 - we released Akka.NET v1.4.21 which fixes this.

Answer (score -1):

I found the problem.

I downgraded my nuget package akka.persistence.mongoDb from 1.4.19 to 1.4.14 and then it worked.
With 1.4.19 akka will only create an EventJournal collection. The Metadata collection is missing.

With 4.1.14 akka also creates the Metadata collection.

Maybe I'm using the MongoDb incorrectly, but that worked for me.

Comment: This is 100% not right. We stopped updating the `metadata` collection upon write because it violated atomicity guarantees https://github.com/akkadotnet/Akka.Persistence.MongoDB/pull/186 - and we've validated these fixes with large users of the plugin.

Our own test suite has to validate write / recovery scenarios like this one and we've validated the fix in external applications too.

Comment: I wonder if we have an issue here https://github.com/akkadotnet/Akka.Persistence.MongoDB/issues/129

Comment: Yep, looks like this is a bug after all - deleting the metadata table exposed it. It's because we don't apply indexes to the collections by default: https://github.com/akkadotnet/Akka.Persistence.MongoDB/blob/552a29eed4c839fe4f91fceeb70bb29eb17d1315/src/Akka.Persistence.MongoDb/reference.conf#L11

Comment: Basicly the answer is not completly wrong :) I found out that there is a problem in the version I am using. It is not the best solution for the mentioned problem but it fixes it.
Great, that you fixed it in a newer version.

Comment: Yep, I was wrong about you being wrong :p